# Connection altervista with watson assistant

Tags: watson-conversation

I'm working on a project for an exam. I created a chatbot with Ibm Cloud using Watson Assistant. After the creation of the chatbot on the platform I connected it to the telegram through node-red and on node-red I added the database also.Now I should connect my chatbot to a website that I created with altervista, but after installing on this the watson assistant plugin, when I insert username password and url (the service credentials of Watson Assistant) and I confirm it give me the error “UNABLE TO CONNECT TO WASTON ASSISTANT SERVICE".Can you help me please?

Comment: Any code to share?

Comment: Can chat with this Watson assistant chatbot through REST API?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are connecting to the Skill API or Assistant API.
2. The Skill API is referred to as Legacy v1 Workspace URL with the workspace ID in the URL.
3. If your skill is linked to an assistant, the API will be referred to as v2.
4. If you are linking to an assistant; you need to add a version number to the URL, for instance: sessions?version=2018-11-21.  Full URL:
   https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/2d7dcb4e-aaaa-bbbb-a11b-4542f92e106e/sessions?version=2018-11-21